# Java Sorting parameters in a new hashmap than returning to main

Tags: java, sorting, machine-learning, hashmap, knn

I'm working on a KNN project and I'm trying to sort the euclidean distances I've calculated in a new hashmap alongside with an index, than take them back to my main.  Here is my code for sorting the distances. However, public int compare() function ONLY returns int, I cannot set it as public double compare() and since all my distances are doubles, I cannot use this function. I will appreciate any help, thank you very much.

```
HashMap<Integer, KnnBundle> knnBundleHashMap = new HashMap<Integer, knnBundle>();

// cnt is the size
for(int i = 0; i< cnt; i++){
knnBundleHaspMap.put(i, newKnnBundle(xarray[i], yarray[i], classes[i], euclid[i]);
}

// not yet sorted
List<KNNBundle>sortedEuclid = new ArrayList<knnBundle>(knnBundleHaspMap.values());

Collections.sort(sortedEuclid, new Comparator<KNNBundle>() {

    public int compare(KNNBundle o1, KNNBundle o2) {
        return o1.getEuclid2() - o2.getEuclid2();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Double.compare`:

```
return Double.compare(o1.getEuclid2(), o2.getEuclid2());
```

In general, you shouldn't use subtraction in compare methods, since it doesn't correctly handle things like overflow, positive zero Vs negative zero, NaN etc.

In Java 8+, you can write this more easily as:

```
   List<KNNBundle>sortedEuclid =
       knnBundleHaspMap.values()
           .stream()
           .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(KNNBundle::getEuclid2))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple aproaches to this.
In Java 8, or newer:

```
List sorted = knnBundleHaspMap.values().stream().sort((b1, b2) -> Double.compare(b1.Euclid2(), b2.Euclid2()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Using the comparator you created, just replace the content of the compare function with this:

```
Double.compare(b1.Euclid2(), b2.Euclid2())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.sort(sortedEuclid, new Comparator<KNNBundle>() {

    public int compare(KNNBundle o1, KNNBundle o2) {
        return o1.getEuclid2() > o2.getEuclid2() ? 1 : o1.getEuclid2() < o2.getEuclid2() ? -1 : 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work correctly because it is not antisymmetrical (it doesn't handle NaN or positive/negative zero correctly).

Comment: @AndyTurner I am clear about the NAN part . But I didn't understand " It wont handle positive/negative zero correctly)" . I usually do this to avoid overflow

Comment: See [this little example](https://ideone.com/wIKYLZ): despite being "equal", +ve and -ve zero are distinct values, and so should have a defined ordering. So, it's not antisymmetry for -ve zero, it's just inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

If JAVA 8

> For Ascending

```
  Comparator comparator = Comparator.comparing(KNNBundle::getEuclid2);
  Collections.sort(sortedEuclid,comparator);
```

> For Descending

```
Comparator comparator = Comparator.comparing(KNNBundle::getEuclid2).reversed();
Collections.sort(sortedEuclid,comparator);
```

If JAVA 7 And JAVA 6

```
Collections.sort(sortedEuclid, new Comparator<KNNBundle>() {

    public int compare(KNNBundle o1, KNNBundle o2) {
        return o1.getEuclid2().compareTo(o2.getEuclid2());
    }
});
```

Comment: "If JAVA 7 And JAVA 6" will only work if `getEuclid2()` returns `Double` as opposed to `double`.

Comment: Yes I accept instead use `Double.compare(o1.getEuclid2(), o2.getEuclid2())`. I thought it is wrapper Double.